# Cache flushing doesn't help after manual deletion of entity references

Tags: caching, entities

I have a little function that deletes specific entity references directly from database. Because of fact that it bypass the whole entity_load / entity_save system it flushes cache of all entities it affects by itself.

The weird thing is that it doesn't work. The references, while not present in the database, still show up on node view / edit pages.

```
  $affected_users = db_select('field_data_fmu_users_firm', 'su')
          ->fields('su', array('entity_id'))
          ->condition('fmu_users_firm_target_id', $user_id, '=')
          ->execute()->fetchCol();

  db_delete('field_data_fmu_users_firm')
      ->condition('fmu_users_firm_target_id', $user_id, '=')
      ->execute();

entity_get_controller('user')->resetCache($affected_users);
```

No special caching module is enabled on the site.

Comment: So why don't you delete them using API? Have you tracked what API is doing when saving them, to be sure you un-do it perfectly? First thought is "revisions", but it may be pretty many other things, too.

Comment: Because it's way faster and I don't really need to care about other modules interaction (hooks, etc.). Considering revisions, it doesn't make much sense since I flush caches and edit the 'data' versions of field table (and not the revision table).

Comment: So... you are leaving reference in latest revision data, and you're surprised reference is still visible? Anyway, not using a CMS at all and coding everything directly is faster **and** more stable & predictable than circumventing CMS functionality.

Comment: As far as I know the newest revision is always stored in (and retrieved from) the fielddata table not the revision table.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about munging the database in a way that has unwanted side-effects and the solution offered by the OP is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: I'd dare to disagree. Though it is not the official approach it can be very useful in certain scenarios that require high performance and at the same time don't change the nodes in way that other modules' hooks would have to be invoked. E.g. it's ideal for 'dead references' deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core has caches. Use the API. If you still do not want to use the API this might be helpful
[Is it proper to perform a db_update on an entity table?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108188/is-it-proper-to-perform-a-db-update-on-an-entity-table/108211#108211)

Comment: I know that core has caches but those should be emptied after entity_get_controller('user')->resetCache($affected_users);

Comment: That will clear the static cache not the cache_field cache

Comment: That will be it.

Answer (score 0):

As @mikeytown2 suggested the problem was in cache_field cache. The solution is quite simple:

```
// Clear field cache
cache_clear_all("field:node:$node->nid", 'cache_field');
```