# How do I get a freshly updated value (i.e. not the cached value) using entity_metadata_wrapper?

Tags: entities, caching

In my code I am inserting a new value into the database directly using db_insert (i.e. inserting an entirely new row).  The type of field, however, already exists in Drupal which is called "field_data_field_email_address".  Previous to the insert call no value existed in the database which is associated with an entity.

Later in code I am relying on entity_metadata_wrapper to retrieve the values associated with the entity.  The problem is that the wrapper doesn't retrieve the most recently inserted value but instead returns nothing.  Yet when I look in the database table I can clearly see the existence of the newly inserted value.

As you may have already guessed I narrowed the issue down to a caching issue because if I clear the Drupal cache the wrapper returns the newly created value just fine.

My question is this: How can I force the entity_metadata_wrapper call to not retrieve the cached version but refresh and return to me the actual current values that exist in the database.  I need my wrapper to represent the freshest data and not the cached version.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The short answer is to never bypass the Field API to update an entity.  The long answer depends on what caching strategies / modules your site is using.

Comment: Actually I think after my db_insert call I can use entity_load() and set the optional parameter $reset to true to update its internal cache.  Testing now, will respond with results in a second.

Comment: Bam! That worked perfectly.

Comment: Related http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/108188/is-it-proper-to-perform-a-db-update-on-an-entity-table

Answer (score 2):

The cache can actually be cleared using the entity_load function and passing a value of true for $reset which will clear the cache and update future references to it including wrappers retrieved from entity_metadata_wrapper:

```
entity_load("node", array($nid), null, true);
```

Comment: I am actually not 100% sure this is accurate.  IIRC, the `$reset` has to do with the static cache, and not {cache_field} nor the entity cache tables.

Comment: Hmm... the result I was looking for worked.  Any insight into what was going on for it to work the way I intended then?

Comment: I am not sure.  I would want someone more familiar with the Entity controllers to weigh in, though mikeytown2 did give a detailed link (and he is a smart dude).

Answer (score 0):

For nodes, I found [this snippet](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7.x) on hook_node insert helpful:

`entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($w->getIdentifier()));`